# python from textfile to array transfer

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a text file which is like:

```
[0.001,0.02,0.003]
[0.004,0.05,0.006]
```

and I want to make an array like this:

```
array([0.001,0.02,0.003],
      [0.004,0.05,0.006]) etc.
```

All element are float.

How can I do like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

```
#First open the text file and turn each line into an element of a list.

with open("file.txt", 'r') as file_handle:
    # convert file contents into a list
    lines = file_handle.read().splitlines()

#Then convert the string into a list

for i in range(len(lines)):
    #remove the "[" and "]" and split where there is a ","
    lines[i] = lines[i].strip("[]").split(",")
    for j in range(len(lines[i])):
        #convert string to float
        lines[i][j] = float(lines[i][j])

print(lines)
```